# mscorlib MissingManifestRessource exception when using WebRTC.Initialize

Tags: visual-studio-2017, webrtc, mscorlib

Here is my code from my new C# Windows Universal Project:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //Initialization of WebRTC worker threads, etc
            try
            {
                WebRTC.Initialize(this.Dispatcher);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            } 
        }
```

I just installed WebRTC with Nuget with

```
Install-Package WebRTC -Version 1.62.0.7
```

and added the line

```
WebRTC.Initialize(this.Dispatcher);
```

When I start the app, after some seconds I receive the message, that I shall start the new debugger in new Visual Studio

[image]

When I start it, I receive the exception:

[image]

If you click on it, it will be bigger.

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 and webRTC. Can you help me with this exception? Is it Visual Studio problem or a WebRTC problem?

Details:

- starting with Debug x64
- "WebRTC": "1.62.0.7"
- Visual Studio 2017 15.4.1

Edit: I updated Visual Studio to 15.5.6 and have still the crash problem without showing me the exception. I asked my question at microsoft feedback.

Edit: If I use English language in Visual Studio, I don't even receive the exception. Visual Studio just stops, wants to start new debugger in new instance of Visual Studio, but can't do it. Only German version shows devenv.exe: Assert failure.

Edit. It is a webRTC problem. `Install-Package WebRTC -Version 1.62.0.7`installs  bad webRTC package.

Comment: It is actually Visual Studio that fell over, not your program.  That isn't terribly unusual for VS2017, it is not a stable product.  Be sure to apply the latest updates, if that doesn't help then use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received more information in Release Mode

> Unhandled exception at 0x749608F2 in VideoConference1.exe: Microsoft
>   C++ exception: Platform::NullReferenceException ^ at memory location
>   0x0D92F41C. HRESULT:0x80004003 Ungültiger Zeiger WinRT information:
>   **deviceId is a required parameter**.

My WebCam didn't work - https://github.com/ortclib/ortclib-sdk/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

WebRtc from NuGet is bad and causes the crash.

Comment: Where should we get a better one?